# Refactoring my index view code with a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to refactor my index view splitting it among two different views to make it more clean and readable.

i split the code previously inside the index in two chunks according to my index controller logic, that i tried after to put inside a helper:

my two index view partials are:
_search_results_products.html.erb

```
  <% if @products.present? %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <% if product.ordinable == true  %>
      <div>
        <%= product.picture? ? image_tag(product.picture_url, :alt => product.name) : image_tag("https://via.placeholder.com/250x250") %>
        <%= product.name %><br>
        <%= product.description %><br>
        <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price)%><br>
        <%= link_to "Show Product", product_path(product) %>
      </div>
      <% else %>
        <h1>No products found!</h1>
      <% end %>
    <%end%>
<%= will_paginate @products%>
  <% else %>
  <h1>No products found!</h1>
  <% end %>
```

_all_products.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% if product.ordinable == true  %>
    <div>
      <%= product.picture? ? image_tag(product.picture_url, :alt => product.name) : image_tag("https://via.placeholder.com/250x250") %>
      <%= product.name %><br>
      <%= product.description %><br>
      <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price)%><br>
      <%= link_to "Show Product", product_path(product) %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <h1>No products found!</h1>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
<%= will_paginate @products%>
```

both of these two partials are inside views/products/index_partials

After i created a method inside the product helper called index_methods_partial which looks like this:

```
module ProductsHelper

  def index_methods_partial
    if params[:term].present?
      @products = Product.where(:ordinable => true).order('created_at DESC').search_by_name_and_description(params[:term]).paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 7
      'views/products/index_partials/search_results_products'
    else
      @products = Product.where(:ordinable => true).order('created_at DESC').paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 7
      'views/products/index_partials/all_products'
    end
  end
end
```

this was the code that was previously inside my product index controller.
which now looks like this, empty

```
  def index
    index_methods_partial
  end
```

Then in my actual index.html.erb i tried to render the helper:

```
<% provide(:title, "Products") %>
<%= render index_methods_partial %>
```

when i go to the index now i get this errors:

```
Missing partial views/products/index_partials/_search_results_products with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/lusa/code/pula/development/myapp/app/views"
  * "/home/lusa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/app/views"
```

and a red error on this line inside the index:

```
<%= render index_methods_partial %>
```

basically what i want to do is to delegate to the helper all the logic about which partial render and give to the index just the call to use the helper. Of course, i could achieve all this refactoring simply putting the logic of my helper inside the index and rendering using the conditional my two partials, but i want to learn how to use helpers and testing is the only way I know to learn. Thank you for the help!

Comment: So what is your question? Did your refactored code not working properly? or you are looking to further refactor it?

Comment: I edited my post with the error i get. I would like to understand how can i properly use a helper to achieve what i want to do.

Comment: Can you make sure that the path and name of the partial file is correct? The error says it unable to find the partial file.

Comment: so i moved the missing partial inside the main views folder and it still can't find it..so i changed the path inside the index_method_partial helper like this to make it match      ''views/search_results_products'', but still the view returns me an arror Missing partial views/_search_results_products.

Comment: is your missing partial in this path: views/products/index_partials/ ?

Comment: Yes. This is my error: http://localhost:3000/products or if i search something from my homepage. ActionView::MissingTemplate in Products#index
Missing partial views/products/index_partials/_all_products with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/lulu/code/levi/development/ezmarkt/app/views"
  * "/home/lulu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/app/views", should i put my partials in another folder and specify the path  inside the helper? What inside the index?

Comment: question: Did you restart the server after adding the new folders and files?

Comment: Yes, i restarted the server. I also tried to add "render" in my helper method, before the partial path, but same error.

Comment: there are two things I guess you need to do:
1- remove 'index_methods_partial' in the index controller, I believe it is not correct unless you are including it in the controller itself, I don't like helper to be included in the controllers, I would prefer MyModules or concerns.
2- make the strings like this 'products/index_partials/search_results_products', rails knows that it is under the 'app/view' part so no need to add 'view/' in the path.

Comment: now it works! Thank you! One last question to understand better the journey my code does. So let's say i go to my localhost:3000/products, how can the index method inside the controller knows what to do? When i  usefrom my homepage the search bar and i look for something, the browser sends the request to the routes and then to the action INDEX, but now, in the index, i don't have anything..how can it know that it has to execute the helper inside the index view? I just have a bit of confusion about the journey my params does through my app.

Comment: Because that's how rails work. What you have available in the helper is available in the view. You explicitely point that you want to render a view by referencing a partial by its absolute path. You could do it in your controller as well and it would work, too. It's how it works.